Is Cordova Facebook4 plugin stopped support?
I'm using Cordova project, I updated to Xcode 15.3, and then the Facebook4 plugin crashed.
I'm wondering if Facebook4 is still supported?
What is the best Facebook sign-in plugin to use in Cordova project with the latest updates of IOS?

Do you have a stack trace to share with us? Some details are missing and without them, it will be hard to help.

Thank you for your reply. once I installed that plugin, the build failed and I'm receiving the error 'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found in xcode

As mentioned in my reply, this plugin is also not that maintained. I can suggest you look at it's repository to see if there are any issues that are related to what you are experiencing.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Assuming this is the plugin you are referring to, you can see that it has been archived in late 2022 and is no longer maintained.
Seeing as it is now mid 2024, you can safely assume this plugin is not compatible with current XCode versions.
From a brief search, I found this plugin, which has more recent maintenance than the previous one, but still has not been touched in a couple of years.

Thank you for your suggestion. This plugin also did not work with xCode last version.
I solved the problem by moving to Capacitor and use facebook-community plugin

@user23575495 - If you have a solution that works, consider posting it as answer so others can also use it. If my answer helped you in any way, consider upvoting it.
